# not update field value on visualpage with Javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

How make changes in outputText and display it? I have issue: It's shown only in function alert(). Here is the code:

```
<apex:page id="page">

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


      <script>
      function temp(){

      document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.form.output}').value = "sdv";

      var v = document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.form.output}').value;
      alert(v);

      }
      </script> 

<apex:form id="form">
<apex:outputText value ="j23652" id="output"/>
<apex:commandButton value="click" oncomplete="temp()"/>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Please **[edit]** your post to clarify a few points using words, not code. What are you trying to achieve? What behavior do you observe? Have you done any debugging in the console? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

outputText renders a span tag, so if you want to update its content, you need to use innerHTML or innerText:

```
  function temp(){
      document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.form.output}').innerText = "sdv";
  }
```